# Livewire lazy loading

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

i have a component who take as parameter display_name and an ip, in the mount method i ping the host with 3 packets to check if its up. so i used lazy loading to speedup page loading.

now when i use more than one components.
when the page loads all the components stay on placeholder view till the last component end his ping then they will change to main view at the same time.

im looking for a way to set component to load individualy without waiting for the others.[example of what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjuro.png)

thats my code

dashboard blade

```
<livewire:dashboard.ping-state name="host1" host="192.168.1.100" lazy key="1" />
<livewire:dashboard.ping-state name="host2" host="192.168.1.50" lazy key="6" />
<livewire:dashboard.ping-state name="host3" host="192.168.1.52" lazy key="7" />
<livewire:dashboard.ping-state name="host4" host="192.168.1.59" lazy key="3" />
```

ping-state

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Dashboard;

use Acamposm\Ping\Ping;
use Acamposm\Ping\PingCommandBuilder;
use Jantinnerezo\LivewireAlert\LivewireAlert;
use Livewire\Component;

class PingState extends Component
{
    use LivewireAlert;
    public string $name;
    public string $host;
    public $avg = 0;
    public string $host_ok;
    public function mount(string $name, string $host)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->ping();
    }
    public function ping()
    {
        $command = (new PingCommandBuilder($this->host))->count(3);
        $ping = (new Ping($command))->run();
        $this->avg = optional($ping)->latency;
        $this->host_ok = $ping->host_status == 'Ok';
        if(!$this->host_ok)
        {
            $this->alert("warning",$this->name,["timer"=>10000]);
            $this->dispatch("unreachableHost");
        }
    }
    public function placeholder()
    {
        return view('placeholders.ping-state',["name"=>$this->name]);
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.dashboard.ping-state');
    }
}
```